# Is there support for "hooks" in OCaml?

Tags: object, hook, ocaml

I [ran across this statement](http://ocaml.org/tutorials/objects.html)

> "I've noticed programmers in xxxx tend to overuse inheritance,
>   possibly because it's the only reasonable way of extending code in
>   that language. A much better and more general way to extend code is
>   usually to use hooks (cf. Apache's module API, [cf. Drupal I might
>   add])."

Have looked for a while,  haven't seen the term "hook" repeated elsewhere in OCaml docs.

Is there some language support for this in OCaml?   Point me in the right direction.  I want sort of class extant (all instances) managed and callbacks,  or not even that,  can a module implement a hook somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like "hook" here could have a lot of different potential definitions.

Answer (score 3):

I would take that as an offhand personal opinion the tutorial author. Hooks aren't part of the OCaml object design. (In my offhand personal opinion, hooks are much, much worse than inheritance.)

Answer (score 1):

The description of **hook** in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/developer/hooks.html) is:

> In general, a hook function is one that Apache will call at some point during the processing of a request. Modules can provide functions that are called, and specify when they get called in comparison to other modules.

The more general term would be **callback function**; languages like C# have special Callback-Objects called **Delegates** because they do not treat functions as (good) first class citizens in their language.
In functional languages like **OCaml**, functions are no different from other values, so you can pass them around just like any integer value without requiring pointers or the like. This makes writing callback functions in these languages so natural, that their programmers don't even need a fancy name for that. ;)

In fact the standard library of OCaml has many **higher-order functions**, that take other functions as arguments. The following is an example:

```
List.iter print_endline ["higher"; "order"; "function"]
```

The `List.iter` function takes the `print_endline` function as *"callback"* argument and applies it to every element of the 2nd argument (the string list). As OCaml allows functions to have side-effects, you could even supply a funciton to `List.iter` that modifies some reference elsewhere in your program.